# SpriteKit collision detection not working as expected

Tags: swift, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

So I have this code inside my `GameScene` class (child of `SKScene`):

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.8)
addChild(balloon)
addChild(monkey)
monkey.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: monkey.frame.size)
monkey.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
monkey.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
monkey.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1//Balloon.categoryBitMask

balloon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: balloon.frame.size)
balloon.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
balloon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
balloon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
balloon.start()
```

I can see that the balloon and the monkey node have touched each other in the simulator, however, nothing happens. I have also conformed to the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol, like so:

```
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("CONTACT!!!")
    }
}
```

Edit: I set `isDynamic = true` and it printed "CONTACT!!" as expected, however  I dont want the objects to be affecting each other's position

Comment: So what do you want then? Only the balloon to move, and then it hits the monkey (without moving the monkey)? Or the monkey getting the balloon? Please explain more.

Comment: @George_E i want the didBegin function to be called on contact, without setting any to dynamic

Comment: But _why_ do you not want to set the objects to dynamic? What's the problem if they are `dynamic`?

Comment: @George_E i don’t want my objects moving on collision, right now once they collide the move other ways automatically